# Why isn't 90 - .Machine$double.eps less than 90?

Tags: r, floating-accuracy

I must be missing something with my understanding of precision here, but I thought that R could represent numbers along a grid with step size `.Machine$double.eps`, but this appears not to be the case; in fact:

```
90 - .Machine$double.eps == 90
# [1] TRUE
```

This is strange to me because these two numbers (1) can be represented and (2) are non-zero:

```
sprintf('%.16a', c(90, .Machine$double.eps))
# [1] "0x1.6800000000000000p+6"  "0x1.0000000000000000p-52"
```

The first place where the difference is numerically non-zero is even more suggestive:

```
90 - 32*.Machine$double.eps < 90
# [1] FALSE
90 - 33*.Machine$double.eps < 90
# [1] TRUE
```

This kind of result points straight to precision issues but there's some gap in my understanding here...

If `90 - .Machine$double.eps == 90`, why isn't `double.eps` larger on my machine?

The results here suggest to me that actually I should have `.Machine$double.eps == 2^5 * .Machine$double.eps`...

Comment: @jogo this is sort of the opposite of most of the floating point questions I've found when looking around. I expect `.1 + .2 != .3`.

Comment: The significant digits of 90 shift the `.Machine$double.eps` away. Try with `91*.Machine$double.eps` - this should give you a difference. (This is clearly a aspect of floating point representation!) Eventually read the definition of a machine.eps: it is the lowest value `eps` for which `1+eps` is not `1`

Comment: @jogo so the conclusion, then, is that the hex exponent (see my edit) is too far apart? (I guess for 64-bit representation they should be within 53?)

Comment: In fact I see `4 - .Machine$double.eps == 4` but `2 - .Machine$double.eps < 2`. Makes sense!

Comment: Try `for (i in 1:10) { print(i - .Machine$double.eps != i) }`. The result is `FALSE` for `i > 2`. The precision is relative to the number `i`.

Comment: @RHertel yep, the key is to look at `sprintf('%.16f', x)` and make sure the exponents of the numbers are _within_ 53, as hinted at  by jogo. This was in fact the gap in my understanding! Thanks.

Comment: The spacing of floating point numbers is not uniform.  The quantity called the "machine epsilon" is the spacing at *1*, which for 64 bit floating point is about 2.22e-16.  The spacing at 90 is about 1.421e-14.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks. Is the rule always to shift _up_ to the larger significance level? i.e., why wasn't 90 sent to infinity (since it's too large relative to 2.22e-16)?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, sorry, I don't understand the question in your last comment.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser in `90 - .Machine$double.eps`, 90 and eps are too far apart. In this case eps was sent to 0 (and 90 was chosen as "dominant"/the important part of the expression), but the other option was to sent 90 to Infinity and treat eps as the "important part". I'm trying to confirm this is always the way things work...

Comment: *"...90 and eps are too far apart."*  You might be thinking about this the wrong way.  Instead of thinking of values being "sent" somewhere, look at what is actually going on: the space between 90 and the next floating point number just below 90 is more than twice the size of `.Machine$double.eps`.  So the number that is closest to `90 - .Machine$double.eps` that is representable as a 64 bit floating point number is 90.

Comment: Reviewing [this web page](https://www.floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect is known as *loss of significance*  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).
The significant digits of 90 shift the `.Machine$double.eps` away. Try

```
(90 - 46*.Machine$double.eps) == 90
```

this should give you `FALSE`.
Definition of a machine.eps: *it is the lowest value `eps` for which `1+eps` is not `1`*

As a rule of thumb (assuming a floating point representation with base 2):
This `eps` makes the difference for the range 1 .. 2,
for the range 2 .. 4 the precision is `2*eps`
and so on.

```
x <- 3.8
(x + 2*.Machine$double.eps) == x
x <- 4
(x + 2*.Machine$double.eps) == x
# ...
x <- 63
(x + 32*.Machine$double.eps) == x
x <- 64
(x + 32*.Machine$double.eps) == x
```

The absolute precision of the floating point representation varies with `x`, but the relative precision is nearly constant over the range of the floating point numbers.

Comment: I would edit this answer since I mention the exact `k` where `(90 - k*.Machine$double.eps) == 90` switches to `FALSE` in my question (and the bound I presented is tighter). Given my question as is, the answer is pretty straightforward -- look at the `%.16a` output I presented. `p+6` is too far from `p-52`. For a non-zero difference to be detected, the we have to increase the latter above `p-47` (i.e. `p-46`)

Comment: Your comment was in fact very helpful! But I don't think this answer follows naturally the question as asked...

Comment: No, that's the title of my question. My question was {body of question}